# How to convert System.IO.Stream into an Image?

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, stream

How can I convert a `Stream` of an image (which I retrieved using the `Album.GetArt` method from the `MediaLibrary`) into a usable `Image` in my application?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Easy... `var img = Bitmap.FromStream(stream);`

Comment: `Bitmap` doesn't seem to be a valid type? is there a reference & using I should add? (im using Windos phone 7 by the way)

Comment: You can also use var image=System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Image.FromStream(stream);

Answer (score 16):

You can run from Bitmaps straight into the arms of Images.

```
Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream);
```

From whence you can do other operations:

```
image.Save(System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot() + "\\Image.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Answer (score 4):

For phone this should work:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
image.SetSource(stream);
```

Answer (score 2):

Great job! I tested this with:

```
Stream streamF = new MemoryStream(); // stream stored in a data file ( FileDB).


Bitmap image = new Bitmap(streamF);
ConsoleWriteImage(image);

//REMEMBER = in console App you must use < using System.Drawing; >
//to handle images but you can't use Form class for present image into some Canvas.
```